# PHP MYQSLi Returning a different value if field is empty

Tags: php, mysqli

This should be simple.... but it's taking a while... Here's the code that's not working (it either shows nothing or the blank state message each time). $show image is the query and I know it's running fine.

```
// BLANK STATE TOGGLE
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($showimage, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if($result == ''){
       echo '<p>Sorry- no image.</p>';
} 
else {
    echo '<p>There is an image!</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know it's running fine? Because the only scenario where `$result` can be `''`/`false` is when the query fails

Comment: Is `$showimage` a mysqli_result? Do you have error reporting enabled and `display_errors` set to "On"? Also, the return value from `mysqli_fetch_array` is either an array or `NULL`. You should probably test against either of those instead of an empty string.

Comment: Okay - they how do I check for an empty table value?

Comment: @Will Start by reading the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) - Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows for the resultset represented by the result parameter.

Comment: @Phil- Okay - think then perhaps mysqli_fetch_array is not a good way to check to see if the field is empty?

Comment: Still no luck - it returns the 'Sorry' result each time when querying fields that have values, and those that don't... still hunting for another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to check for the existence of rows in the result from your query, why don't you simplify it like this

```
// $db is your MySQLi connection object

$query = 'SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `table` WHERE `something` = ?';
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $something);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($rowCount);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

if ($rowCount > 0) : ?>
<p>There is an image!</p>
<?php else : ?>
<p>Sorry- no image.</p>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

`mysqli_fetch_array` returns null if there is no match in the database. So you need to check for null.

You may need to try this:

if `$showimage` is your query ..

```
//This should run fine
//$link is ur connection
$new_result = mysqli_query($link,$showimage);


$result = mysqli_fetch_array($new_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if($result == null){
       echo '<p>Sorry- no image.</p>';
} 
else {
    echo '<p>There is an image!</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your mysqli_query call is confusing. The manual page is here if you feel like cleaning it up - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php